# Implementation of trait not general enough since I can't specify small enough lifetime

Tags: rust, traits, higher-rank-types

(This is a bit of a long one, since I'm not exactly sure where exactly the error is, sorry!)

I have a trait

```rust
trait FilterComponent<'a, F>: Sized {
    fn from_option(f: Option<&'a F>) -> Option<Self>;
}
```

which I am using to get a &F from an external crate and convert it into a type such as `Option<&F>` or `&F`, returning a `Err(())` in the case where the conversion is not desirable. I then pass the unwrapped value (if it is `Some`) to a function that takes that implementing type. I'll stick with the implementation for just a `&F`

```rust
impl<'a: 'b, 'b, F> FilterComponent<'a, F> for &'b F {
    fn from_option(f: Option<&'a F>) -> Option<Self> {
        f
    }
}
```

Since I want to do this for a list of functions, each with potentially different choices of `FilterComponent`, I create a series of traits to turn a general function into one I can sue, as follows:

```rust
//the type that implements GraphFilter and is returned by the IntoGraphFilter trait
struct FunctionFilter<F, G, Func>
where
    G: for<'a> FilterComponent<'a, F>,
    Func: Fn(G) -> bool,
{
    func: Func,
    _phantom: PhantomData<(F, G)>,
}

//trait to turn a function into a nameable type we can implement the
//typeless GraphFilter trait for (to avoid unconstrained type parameters)
trait IntoGraphFilter<F, G> {
    type Output: GraphFilter;
    fn into_filter(self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<F, G, Func> IntoGraphFilter<F, G> for Func
where
    G: for<'a> FilterComponent<'a, F>,
    Func: Fn(G) -> bool,
{
    type Output = FunctionFilter<F, G, Func>;
    fn into_filter(self) -> Self::Output {
        FunctionFilter {
            func: self,
            _phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<F, G, Func> GraphFilter for FunctionFilter<F, G, Func>
where
    G: for<'a> FilterComponent<'a, F>,
    Func: Fn(G) -> bool,
{
}

//The final trait I use to store my generic functions
trait GraphFilter {}

//The storing struct
struct Storer {
    filters: Vec<Box<dyn GraphFilter>>,
}

impl Storer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            filters: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    fn add_filter<F, G: for<'a> FilterComponent<'a, F>>(
        &mut self,
        func: impl IntoGraphFilter<F, G>,
    ) {
        self.filters.push(Box::new(func.into_filter()))
    }
}

fn main() {
    Storer::new().add_filter(|foo: &()| true);
}
```

Then, since I want to store these filters dynamically, I have some struct that stores `dyn GraphFilter`s in a `Vec` within some struct. To add them, I have a function impl'd for this struct with the signature:

```
fn add_filter<F, G: for<'a> FilterComponent<'a, F>>(&mut self, filter: impl IntoGraphFilter<F, G>)
```

But when I try to actually use this function like so:

```
storage.add_filter(|foo: &Foo| {false});
```

I get the error:
"implementation of `FilterComponent` is not general enough
`FilterComponent<'0, Foo>` would have to be implemented for the type `&Foo`, for any lifetime `'0`...
...but `FilterComponent<'1, Foo>` is actually implemented for the type `&'1 Foo`, for some specific lifetime `'1`"
Looking at my impl for `&F`, I only get `FilterComponent<'a, F>` for `'a` longer than my types own lifetime, which in the case of `|foo: &Foo| {false}` should be any lifetime.
I'm not really sure where to go from here: I've tried modifying everything to remove the `for<'a>` but I ended up with an error that `'a` is trying to outlive `'static`

Edit: In editing to make reproducible, the compiler is now also telling me that my associated type won't live long enough in the definition of add_filter, which is a problem I had previously encountered but only seems to show up occasionaly, probably being hidden by other errors - any hints for fixing this would be appreciated too!

Comment: Please add a [mre], your example is riddled with syntax errors and missing types.

Comment: `&Foo` can never satisfy the constraint `for<'a> FilterComponent<'a, F>` because `&Foo` really `&'x Foo` and there is NO way for that `'x` to be at least as long as EVERY other lifetime `'a` (after all, that is what `for <'a>` means - its 'for every lifetime'). Funny enough I basically answered the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77819887/explicitly-boxing-lifetime-bound-conversion-closures-in-rust/77820926#77820926) in a totally different context a couple days ago

Comment: Is `FilterComponent` only ever implemented for references?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It is implemented for &F and Option<&F> and could be implemented for other similar reference containing types

Comment: Why do you need it for `Option<&F>`? It will return `Option<Option<&F>>`.

Comment: This can be made to work, but it requires very complicated traits and obscure user code. The question is, do you want that?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman in the actual code the options in the Trait are results instead, so I can return sometimes return an error from the conversion or turn an error into a none value in the case of Option<&F>